# Install xorg in Arch Linux

Tags: xorg, arch-linux

I am trying to install Xorg on my Arch Linux VM, what I have done so far:

- edited `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` and uncommented my country mirror
- `dhcpcd eth0`
- `pacman -Syy`
- `pacman -S xorg-server`, which also started a few updates
- a few errors led me to delete `/usr/bin/tzselect`, `/usr/sbin/zdump` and `/usr/sbin/zic`
- continued with `pacman -S xorg-server`

Finally it looks like it's installing, but in the end I got a lot of errors:

```
...
xorg-server: key "946...." is unknown
key "946..." could not be looked up remotely
failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature))
```

### Update 2012-04-09 21:17

Just tried to run `pacman -S sudo` and I saw all the errors, and it indicates to run `pacman-key --init`, hoping this will solve the problem.

#### Edit

That took a lot of time, but I still get errors.

### Update 2012-04-11 01:55

I edited `/etc/pacman.conf` and set up `SigLevel = Never`

Answer (score 1):

As you've figured out, its a PGP signature error. Since spring of 2012, pacman (the Arch Linux package manager) requires packages to be signed. You can either disable the signature requirement (not recommended) or run the following:

```
pacman-key --init
```

The above command may take a while. If you can, in another terminal run `ls -R /` a couple of times to help generate randomness. Once the init command is done, you need to provide pacman with the list of the keys which are accepted (this step is critical).

```
pacman-key --populate archlinux
```

This command may ask you to sign the keys. You'll want to say yes to all of them.

Source: [pacman-key article on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman-key)